# android split the circle without taking the origin into consideration

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I'm trying to split the circle into something of this sort:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNg3E.png
I want to color the major arc part of the circle with transparent color and minor arc of the circle with black color. Here is what I have tried, but unable to reach the final goal:

```
public class SplitCircleDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final Bitmap mBitmap;

    private final Paint mPaint;

    private final Paint mBackGroundPaint,mTransparentPaint;



    private final RectF mRectF;

    private final int mBitmapWidth;

    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    private Context mCtx;


    public SplitCircleDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, Context mContext) {

        mCtx = mContext;
        mBitmap=bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mBackGroundPaint = new Paint();
        mTransparentPaint=new Paint();
        mBackGroundPaint.setColor(0x97021829);
        mTransparentPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mBackGroundPaint.setDither(true);
        mBackGroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        // NOTE: we assume bitmap is properly scaled to current density
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 0, 180, false, mBackGroundPaint);
//        canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 0, 45, true, mTransparentPaint);
//        canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 45, 135, true, mBackGroundPaint);
//        canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 135, 180, true, mTransparentPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);

        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }



}
```

Any help on this pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to do it with canvas `clipPath()`:

```
    // First we draw draw backgroudn, it should be cropped with path too
    canvas.drawOval(mRectF, paintBackground);

    // Creating path that will cover small area on the circle, 
    // it might be triangle or rectancel or what ever. 
    // Currently it is triangle between top and left rect centers.
    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, mRectF.width() / 2f);
    path.lineTo(mRectF.height() / 2f, 0);
    path.close();

    // Clipping canvas to path and drawing small area
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawOval(mRectF, paintArc);
    canvas.restore();
```

[image: Drawing arc on Android]

Comment: that is amazing, now clipping region is at say NorthWest corner, I want to get it to bottom(SOUTH), also I want to increase the region of red zone a bit, how do I do these both..thanks a lot again, you saved me

Comment: use `path` to buid triangle a the bottom, something like this: `path.reset(); path.lineTo(0, mRectF.height());path.lineTo(x, mRectF.height());path.lineTo(0, y);path.close();` Change x and y to achive desire effect.

Comment: I tried something like this, to form a triangle at bottom, but no luck path.lineTo(mRectF.width()/2f,-mRectF.width()/2f);
        path.lineTo(-mRectF.width()/2f,-mRectF.width()/2f);

        path.close();

Comment: Why do you use negative value? Use example above and set `x = mRectF.width() / 2f` and `y = mRectF.height() / 2f`